# Minimizing DB hits in Django: .values_list() dependent on previous .filter() clause

Tags: python, django

I'm running into a problem with a DB query in Django.

My DB (models.py):

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

class Combination(models.Model):
    food1 = models.ForeignKey(Food, related_name='food1')
    food2 = models.ForeignKey(Food, related_name='food2')
    ...
```

The order of foods in combination does not matter for my problem. 
 
Additionally each combination can exist multiple times (and in both directions).

E.g. food1="chocolate" & food2="fruit" is the same as food2="chocolate" & food1="fruit"
and both combinations exist multiple times.

If I want to find all combination including a specific food (identified by food_id)
I am currently resorting to the following queries:

```
combinations1 = Combination.objects.filter(food1=food_id).values_list('food2')
combinations2 = Combination.objects.filter(food2=food_id).values_list('food1')
```

It works but requires more processing later. I tried to use Q objects with OR,
but I didn't suceed because the column extracted depends on the filter...

I know this solution is far from elegant. Should I rather use a custom Field or a CommaSeparatedIntegerField instead of two seperate food fields in Combination?
Is there a way to get all requested values (from both columns) with one DB Hit?

Thank's for helping me out!

Cheers,
Oliver

Comment: Not sure I understand why a OR:ed Q object don't work for you. What are you doing with the data after retrieving it?

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough: I intent to use these list further with:

.annotate(num_node=Count('node2')).order_by('-num_node')


Which again is dependent on the column...

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is the use of the Q object, something like

```
qs = Combination.objects.filter(Q(food1=food_id)|Q(food2=food_id).values_list('food1', 'food2')
combinations = set()
for row in qs:
   if row[0] == food_id:
       combinations.append(row[1])
   else:
       combinations.append(row[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't

```
itertools.chain(Food(id=food_id).food1.all(), Food(id=food_id).food2.all())
```

what you're after?

And if order of Foods in combinations is irrelevant, why not use a `ManyToManyField(Food)` on `Combination`?
Then `Food(id=food_id).combination_set.all()` will be all combinations that have that particular food in them.